# JAVA - Create a file in linux server

Tags: java, linux, file, server, directory

I'm trying to create a directory and a file in a linux server. I have all the permissions and it works in local windows machine ("C:\home\images\784).But when I put the server url it doesn't work.

The directory is:

```
String directorio = "10.30.10.117:/home/images/784/"
File folder = new File(directorio);
Boolean bol = folder.mkdirs();
```

When the file "folder" is created it's absolute path is:

```
"10.30.10.117:\home\images\784"
```

When I want to write the file I get this exception (the directory doesn't exist)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 10.30.10.117:\home\images\1508-1-N.png (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to connect via SMB or CIFS to a windows server you need to use a library which supports that protocol.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the machine "10.30.10.117" is on your local network and if you have the permission to create file on that machine then the problem is

```
File folder = new File("//10.30.10.117:/home/images/784/");
File file   = new File("//10.30.10.117:/home/images/784/1508-1-N.png");
folder.mkdirs();
file.createNewFile();
```

Before write to file create it.

But if the machine "10.30.10.117" is on external network for your machine then you can't create a file or folder directly from your machine. You need ftp connection vb...

Comment: Thank you. It was a usefull answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
String directorio = "10.30.10.117:/home/images/784/"
```

You seem to wrongly assume that the Java File class has the power to magically connect to a **remote** system in order to create a directory there.

Wrong. You can only create a file on the **local** file system.

Simple as that.